# Ensuring that critical software does not fail

Tags: autostart, fancontrol, dell-vostro

I have a Dell Vostro 5490, which like many laptops from dell have a loud fan which is not well regulated.

To solve this I have installed *[i8kutils](https://github.com/vitorafsr/i8kutils)* to control the fan and *[dell-bios-fan-control](https://github.com/TomFreudenberg/dell-bios-fan-control)* to release the fan control from BIOS. These systems work fine, and I can manually control the fan speed, and now I want to add the automatic control on startup.Since I have to turn off the BIOS control it seems to me that in case the i8k program would for whatever reason crash the computer might overheat and fry my CPU.

What safety measures can I use to make sure this does not happen? Is there any way of making sure the daemon gets restarted in case it crashes?